# Magento Product Release

Tags: magento2.4, hosting

I am new to Magento development. I need to create an eCommerce website for an external client.

I have installed Magento 2.4 in my system and created a store.

My question is how to release this store to clients for testing.

Can I just copy-paste the entire Magento code into another system or how I have to provide it same store to the client for testing.

Please Reply...

Answer (score 0):

```
php bin/magento maintenance:enable --ip=192.0.2.10 --ip=192.0.2.11
```

Get client ip address and replace it wth above ip address,Magento will allow above ip's as whitelist to access your site.

```
php bin/magento maintenance:disable
```

**Note**: If you try to access that url during maintenance flag, from different ip address,you will see maintenance  page error.So kindly disable it after your work completed.